# gmail API won't work, cannot deconstruct property 'client_secret'

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, gmail-api

I tried following the instructions in the gmail tutorial and it won't work.
I downloaded the credentials.json file and index.js file and whenever I run it with node . it gives me the following error:

```
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
         ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `client_secret` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at authorize (/var/www/html/index.js:26:65)
    at fs.readFile (/var/www/html/index.js:16:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code, without seeing your code we cant help you debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the tutorial [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)

It goes though with you creating the credentials.json file for a web application.  Remember to enable the Gmail api.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    userId: 'me',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const labels = res.data.labels;
    if (labels.length) {
      console.log('Labels:');
      labels.forEach((label) => {
        console.log(`- ${label.name}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No labels found.');
    }
  });
}
```

unauthorized_client  normally means that you are requesting a scope but you haven't added it in Google developer console. or there is something wrong with the refresh token.

If you have any issues with the authorization try deleting the file in TOKEN_PATH this should cause the authorization window to popup again and you can try again to request access.

Comment: I deleted the token.json and now it works! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your credentials.json file, check if the object key is different than "installed". In my case, the first time I was testing gmail api, I chose "web application" when I created the application on console.developers.google.com/. So, my credentials.json had a "web" key, instead of "installed", which is the one the api page gives you as an example.

You can go back to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs and click the "Enable the Gmail API" once again, but choose the "Desktop" option this time if you are testing it with at localhost.

Comment: Thank you but I already tried changing it to installed and got the following error:
````The API returned an error: Error: unauthorized_client````